# Switching values between columns IF

Tags: powerquery

I have a various columns with numeric data in them, and I was wondering if I can somehow switch values between columns IF a condition is met - if value in columna A is equal to 0 and value in column B is deifferent that 0, then I would like to swich those values so that column A has a value from B and vice versa.

I was trying to do that with Table.ReplaceValue but the problem is, that once I replace a value in column A with that from column B, my condition won't be met during next replacement.

Example:
If a Table looks like that:

| PART NO | COLUMN A | COLUMN B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 80 |
| 3 | 130 | 140 |

I'd like it to change like this:

| PART NO | COLUMN A | COLUMN B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | 0 |
| 2 | 80 | 0 |
| 3 | 130 | 140 |

Answer (score 0):

Add column .. custom column...  Column A.1

```
 = if (insert your test here)  then [COLUMN B] else [COLUMN A]
```

Add column .. custom column...  Column B.1

```
= if [COLUMN A] = [COLUMN A.1] then [COLUMN B] else [COLUMN A]
```

then right click and remove original two columns, and rename these

Comment: ... or use code to rename and remove: `Rmv = Table.RemoveColumns(PriorStep1, {"COLUMN A", "COLUMN B"})` followed by `Ren = Table.RenameColumns(Rmv, {{"COLUMN A.1", "COLUMN A"}, {"COLUMN B.1", "COLUMN B"}})`